# Sequelize keep creates a table that I deleted from DB and models

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize and Nodejs to manage the MYSQL server.

For some reason, Sequelize keeps creating a table that I deleted from DB and models.
I guess it's related to `cash` or `.sync()`.

Any idea why, and how to prevent it from happening?

Comment: Are you sure it's not related to "migrations"?

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem.
I was using typescript and the file I had created for the model was called 'city.model.ts'. After removing it from my src and building, it was still in the output directory from my tsconfig.
After deleting the output directory and rebuilding the table was no longer being created.
Hope this helps.